# Can $\mathbb C^*$ be expressed as a direct product of two proper non-trivial subgroups ?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, direct-product

Is it true that $\mathbb C^*$  can be expressed as a direct product of two proper non-trivial subgroups ?

Comment: Any ideas what could give such a decomposition?

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathbb C^*$ means: nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.

Comment: Can you think of a surjective homomorphism onto a one-dimensional topological group?